# Нужно создать блок, видимость которого зависит от средней кнопки мыши

Tags: javascript, css

Необходимо изменение видимости блока по клику средней кнопкой мыши.
Код я написал, но он не работает.
В чём ошибка?
Заранее извиняюсь, в JS и JQuery я только начинающий и изучаю по мере необходимости.

```js
function middleClick(e) {
  if (e.which == 2) {
    if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "none") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "block")
    }

    if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "block") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "none")
    }
  }
```

```css
#red_block {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  right: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  bottom: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red_block"></div>
```

Comment: А где надо кликнуть среднюю кнопку мыши что бы красный блок исчез?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного исправил ваш код. 
1) В конце JS-кода добавлено несколько фигурных скобок, без которых код не работает.
2) В вашем коде есть только функция. Чтобы эта функция работала при нажатии средней кнопки мыши, к ней нужно добавить обработчик событий. Добавить обработчик событий можно двумя способами - `onmousedown` и `addEventListener`.
3) Событие `click` не подходит, т.к. оно не может использовать среднюю кнопку мыши, поэтому было выбрано событие `mousedown`.
Вот исправленный код:

```js
function middleClick(e) {
  if (e.which == 2) {
    if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "none") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "block")
    }

    if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "block") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "none")
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener('mousedown', middleClick);
```

```css
#red_block {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  right: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  bottom: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red_block"></div>
```

Если нужно, чтобы на клик средней кнопки мыши реагировал только блок, в строку
`document.getElementById('red_block').addEventListener('mousedown', middleClick);`
после `document` добавить код:
`.getElementById('red_block')`

Comment: Супер...)) А как ты думаешь, почему я его в комменте спросил где должен происходить клик?

Comment: Неужели нужно, чтобы клик происходил на фоне? А то я думаю, как будет блок обратно возвращаться. Получается, что в этом коде блок будет невозможно вернуть. =)

Comment: Вот - Вот )))  и я об этом)))

Comment: Я не знаю, что ему надо... ))) Но думаю фон на много логичнее, по этому решил уточнить...

Comment: Прошу прощения за срок ответа.
Суть дела вот в чём: нужно меню, которое будет открываться при клике по колесу мыши в любом месте документа.
Код правленный выше, как и сказано в комментариях, только скрывает его, но вызвать повторно не даёт.
Как сделать так, что бы блок произвольно менял своё состояние переключаясь между "вкл" и "выкл" по среднему клику мыши?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое сообществу за помощь, глупо, но я забыл про "else if".

```js
function middleClick(e) {
  if (e.which == 2) {
    if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "none") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "block")
    }

    else if ($('#red_block').css('display') == "block") {
      $("#red_block").css("display", "none")
    }
  }
}
document.addEventListener('mousedown', middleClick);
```

```css
#red_block {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  right: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  bottom: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red_block"></div>
```